# How do I fix 'please minimize large stack variables' error while testing my anchor program?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, transactions, pda, account

I'm getting the following error using Anchor 0.25.0 `Stack offset of 11792 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 7696 bytes, please minimize large stack variables` initializing my accounts on local testing.

I'm initializing a **boxed** account (Board) that represents a 10x10 optional board, where each cell contains a public key and some values.

```
pub struct Create<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = user,
        space = 8 + board::MAXIMUM_SIZE,
        seeds = [b"board"],
        bump
    )]
    pub board: Box<Account<'info, Board>>,
   ... etc
```

`pub const MAXIMUM_SIZE: usize = 32 + 8 + 1 + (100 * (32 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1));`

public initializer function that is failing

````
pub fn create(ctx: Context<Create>) -> Result<()> {
    let pixel_board = &mut ctx.accounts.board;
    pixel_board.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("board").unwrap();
    pixel_board.count = 0;
    pixel_board.gov = *ctx.accounts.gov.key;

    Ok(())
}
```

any tips / pointers on how to reduce this the stack variables here? I'd like to scale beyond 10x10 at some point if possible. Thank you in advance
````

Answer (score 3):

This will be a bit tough if you're using Anchor, since it automatically deserializes and reserializes variables for you, which means it will try to put the whole type on the stack.

I'm not sure if this will work, but you can try to have it as an unchecked account, then allocate it on the heap using a `Box`, ie `let boxed = Box<Board>::try_from_slice(account_info.borrow_data()).unwrap();`

Comment: awesome! i'll give this a try. thx

Comment: Any thoughts on using zero copy? https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/attr.account.html

Comment: Zero-copy is an excellent option too, since you're just reinterpreting the account data as some other type.  Note that it's much more strict on the types supported compared to the normal Borsh-style format

Comment: thanks! posting a followup question here: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3905/setting-account-values-using-zero-copy-pda-on-anchor