# Setting account values using Zero Copy PDA on Anchor

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, pda

I've created a 2D array (10x10) that using a PDA and zero_copy. Here is how I set it up.

```
pub fn setBoard(ctx: Context<SetBoard>, increment: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let mut board = ctx.accounts.board.load_mut()?;
        pixel_board.count += increment;

        pixel_board.board[2 as usize][2 as usize] = Some(BoardValues {
            setter: ctx.accounts.user.key.clone(),
        });

        match results {
            Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
            _ => ()
        }

        Ok(())
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SetBoard<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"board"],
        bump,
    )]
    pub board: AccountLoader<'info, Board>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        constraint = &board.load()?.govKey == governanceAccount.key,
    )]
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we check against govKey
    pub governanceAccount: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[zero_copy]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct BoardValues {
    pub setter: Pubkey,
}

#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(packed)]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Board {
    pub govKey: Pubkey, // 32 for pubkey
    pub count: u64, // 8 for u64
    pub bump: u8, // 1 for bump
    pub board: [[Option<BoardValues>; 10]; 10], // 32 + 1 (discriminant) = 33
}
```

After initializing the board, I console log the board and get the following during `anchor test`:

```
{
  govKey: PublicKey {
    _bn: <BN: redacted>
  },
  count: <BN: 1>,
  bump: 255,
  board: [
    [
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null
    ],
    [
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null
    ],
    [
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null
    ],
    [
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null
    ],
    [
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null
    ],
    [
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null
    ],
    [
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null
    ],
    [
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null
    ],
    [
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null
    ],
    [
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null
    ]
  ]
}
```

I'm at a loss for why everything is null at the moment - any tips / pointers?

Comment: quick update, I removed "Option" here to "[[BoardValues; 10]; 10]" and this seemed to work. Not sure if anyone has a similar experience working with Option on zero_copy...